# Cant figure out how to get this name generator working

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

For school I'm doing an assignment where we need to make a random name generator for male and female names and we have to put numbers in front of it but i can't figure out how to do that. The generator itself is working but its the number part i can't figure out. The numbers need to go from 1 to a maximum of 100.

```
var number = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * number.length);
var counter = number[randomnumber];

document.write("Female Names");
document.write("<br>");
function femaleName (){
// My variables.
// Klinkers.
var klinker = ["o", "a", "i", "e", "u"];
var randomnumberk = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker = klinker[randomnumberk];
var randomnumberk1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker1 = klinker[randomnumberk1];
var randomnumberk2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker2 = klinker[randomnumberk2];
var randomnumberk3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker3 = klinker[randomnumberk3];
var randomnumberk4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker4 = klinker[randomnumberk4];
// Medeklinkers.
var medeklinker = ["b", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "z",]
var randomnumbermk = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker = medeklinker[randomnumbermk];
var randomnumbermk1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker1 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk1];
var randomnumbermk2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker2 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk2];
var randomnumbermk3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker3 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk3];
var randomnumbermk4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker4 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk4];
document.write(number, randomklinker, randommedeklinker, randomklinker1, randommedeklinker1, randomklinker2);
document.write("<br>");
}

for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
femaleName();
}

document.write("<br>");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Male names");
document.write("<br>");

function maleName (){
// My variables.
// Klinkers.
var klinker = ["o", "a", "i", "e", "u"];
var randomnumberk = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker = klinker[randomnumberk];
var randomnumberk1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker1 = klinker[randomnumberk1];
var randomklinker2 = klinker[randomnumberk2];
var randomnumberk3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker3 = klinker[randomnumberk3];
var randomnumberk4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker4 = klinker[randomnumberk4];
// Medeklinkers.
var medeklinker = ["b", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "z",]
var randomnumbermk = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker = medeklinker[randomnumbermk];
var randomnumbermk1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker1 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk1];
var randomnumbermk2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker2 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk2];
var randomnumbermk3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker3 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk3];
var randomnumbermk4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker4 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk4];
document.write(randommedeklinker, randomklinker, randommedeklinker1, randomklinker1, randommedeklinker2);
document.write("<br>");
}

for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  maleName();
}
```

I hope that someone here can help me with this problem.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help. i have been able to fix the problem now thanks to everyones help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code needs improvement. For now, here is a solution...

document.write(**number**, randomklinker, randommedeklinker...);

change number to **(i+1)**

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of questions always make me doubt what's the best answer. Obviously, the solution provided by [RRZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4800004/rrz) works and should be marked as answer. *However*, I believe that if you make sure your code is written in a clear and concise matter, you would've spotted it yourself!

I don't want to do your homework for you, but I do want to show you another way of writing this program.

- Try to subdivide your problem in to small problems:

  - Getting the numbers 1 to 5
  - Getting a random vowel
  - Getting a random consonant
  - Chaining vowels and consonants together in sequences
  - Rendering names to the document
- Try to think which of these problems occur a lot, give them their own functions
- Start by defining the "settings" of your program

  - How many names do you want to generate
  - What's the pattern of a female name
  - What's the pattern of a male name

To make this a bit more tangible, I've implemented your code in a way that answers to these bullets:

```js
// Settings
var NR_OF_NAMES = 6,
    // K = Klinker, M = Medeklinker
    FEMALE_NAME_PATTERN = "KMKMK",
    MALE_NAME_PATTERN = "MKMKM";

function getRandomIntBelow(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
};

function getRandomFromArray(array) {
  return array[getRandomIntBelow(array.length)];
}

function getRandomKlinker() {
  return getRandomFromArray(["o", "a", "i", "e", "u"]);
}


function getRandomMedeklinker() {
  return getRandomFromArray(["b", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "z"]);
}

function getNameByPattern(pattern) {
  return pattern
    .split("") // Array of characters
    .map(function(code) {
       // Replace M by medeklinker
      if (code === "M") return getRandomMedeklinker();
      // Replace K by klinker
      if (code === "K") return getRandomKlinker();      
    })
    .join(""); // Back to string
}

// Document creation:

// Render a list of names
function writeNameBlock(pattern, count) {
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(i + 1 + ". ");
    document.write(getNameByPattern(pattern));
  }
}

// Render the outlinse and include two lists
document.write("Female Names");
writeNameBlock(FEMALE_NAME_PATTERN, NR_OF_NAMES);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Male names");
writeNameBlock(MALE_NAME_PATTERN, NR_OF_NAMES);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what you want, but if it's to add the sequence number before each name, you just need to declare a variable as `i + 1` (plus any formatting, like a space after).  The `+ 1` is because `i` is zero indexed.  Hope this helps.  With each iteration of the loop, the sequence number increments.

```js
var number = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * number.length);
var counter = number[randomnumber];

document.write("Female Names");
document.write("<br>");
function femaleName (){
var sequenceNumber = i + 1 + ' ';
// My variables.
// Klinkers.
var klinker = ["o", "a", "i", "e", "u"];
var randomnumberk = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker = klinker[randomnumberk];
var randomnumberk1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker1 = klinker[randomnumberk1];
var randomnumberk2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker2 = klinker[randomnumberk2];
var randomnumberk3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker3 = klinker[randomnumberk3];
var randomnumberk4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker4 = klinker[randomnumberk4];
// Medeklinkers.
var medeklinker = ["b", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "z",]
var randomnumbermk = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker = medeklinker[randomnumbermk];
var randomnumbermk1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker1 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk1];
var randomnumbermk2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker2 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk2];
var randomnumbermk3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker3 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk3];
var randomnumbermk4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker4 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk4];
document.write(sequenceNumber, randomklinker, randommedeklinker, randomklinker1, randommedeklinker1, randomklinker2);
document.write("<br>");
}

for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
femaleName();
}

document.write("<br>");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Male names");
document.write("<br>");

function maleName (){
var sequenceNumber = i + 1 + ' ';
// My variables.
// Klinkers.
var klinker = ["o", "a", "i", "e", "u"];
var randomnumberk = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker = klinker[randomnumberk];
var randomnumberk1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker1 = klinker[randomnumberk1];
var randomnumberk2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker2 = klinker[randomnumberk2];
var randomnumberk3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker3 = klinker[randomnumberk3];
var randomnumberk4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * klinker.length);
var randomklinker4 = klinker[randomnumberk4];
// Medeklinkers.
var medeklinker = ["b", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "z",]
var randomnumbermk = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker = medeklinker[randomnumbermk];
var randomnumbermk1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker1 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk1];
var randomnumbermk2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker2 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk2];
var randomnumbermk3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker3 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk3];
var randomnumbermk4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * medeklinker.length);
var randommedeklinker4 = medeklinker[randomnumbermk4];
document.write(sequenceNumber, randommedeklinker, randomklinker, randommedeklinker1, randomklinker1, randommedeklinker2);
document.write("<br>");
}

for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  maleName();
}
```